# apache poi disable default footer for the first page

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

I am trying to create a word document in which I will have no footer only in the first page and a footer for the rest of the pages. I wrote the following code (I also tried to change -reverse- the order of creation of `footer` and `footerFirst` objects) but that did not help. I still have the default footer on all pages.

How should I disable the footer from the first page? Thanks in advance.

```
private XWPFDocument initDocument(String FILE) throws Exception{
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
    if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();


    // create header start
    XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

    //XWPFParagraph paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
    if (paragraph == null)
        paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setFontSize(11);
    run.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
    run.setText("Some company info in the footer");

    XWPFFooter footerFirst = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.FIRST);
    paragraph = footerFirst.getParagraphArray(0);
    if (paragraph == null)
        paragraph = footerFirst.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText(" ");



    return document;
}
```

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using?

Comment: @AxelRichter the version 4.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That there is a different header set for first page only, means not that this header will also be shown. In `Word GUI` there is a checkbox `[x] Different First Page` in Header & Footer Tools to achieve that.

And according `Office Open XML Part 4 - Markup Language Reference` there must a boolean `XML` element `titlePg` be set to determine that there is a title page present.

In old `apache poi` versions using `XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy`  this `XML` element `titlePg` can only be set using underlying low level objects using `document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().addNewTitlePg();`.

But using current `apache poi` versions (since `3.16`) there is no need using `XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy`  directly. Now there is `XWPFDocument.createHeader` and `XWPFDocument.createFooter` using a `HeaderFooterType`. This sets `titlePg` flag in `XML` when `HeaderFooterType.FIRST` is used.

Complete example which sets and uses `HeaderFooterType.FIRST` and `HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT`:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class CreateWordFooters {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body... first page");
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("The Body... second page");

  // create first page footer
  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("First page footer...");

  // create default footer
  footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Default footer...");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordFooters.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();


 }
}
```